# find the least number whose square is of form 1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_0. Where "_" could be any 1 digit number

Tags: java, string, long-integer

In my recent interview, the interviewer asked me to
 `write a Java program to find the least number whose square is of form 1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_0. Where "_" could be any 1 digit number.`
And I'd stuck in that.

Can anybody help me with the logic to be implemented?

Comment: Maybe there is more opimized solution, but using a `BigInteger` and iterating until one number matches the desired pattern (can be verified with a regex after doing `toString()` on the number) is simple (though not efficient) solution.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse: actually I'd no idea how to solve that.

Comment: @amit: can you put the code snippet for matching the pattern using regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the minimum number of that format is `1020304050607080900` which has square root `1010101010.10...`.  And the maximum number of that format is `1929394959697989990` which has square root approx. `1389026623.11`.

Start at the lower bound, and iterate through to the upper bound.  You use regex or even rudimentary string character matching, just check that the first char is 1, the 3rd char is 2, etc.

Also, I think a `long` would be sufficient for this.

EDIT:

I just ran this on my machine, it took around 2 minutes.  I suck at regex so I did it primitive style.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (long l = 1010101010; l < 1389026623; l++) {
        long squared = l * l;
        String s = Long.toString(squared);
        if (s.charAt(0) != '1') continue;
        if (s.charAt(2) != '2') continue;
        if (s.charAt(4) != '3') continue;
        if (s.charAt(6) != '4') continue;
        if (s.charAt(8) != '5') continue;
        if (s.charAt(10) != '6') continue;
        if (s.charAt(12) != '7') continue;
        if (s.charAt(14) != '8') continue;
        if (s.charAt(16) != '9') continue;
        if (s.charAt(18) != '0') continue;
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

The result was `1929374254627488900` (this is the squared number).  Therefore, the root number is `1389019170`.  Also note this is the **only** number I found matching the pattern, not just the minimum.

Comment: You can even skip all numbers that are not multiples of 10 since the ones digit of the square has to be 0.

Answer (score 2):

A simple though probably not efficient solution will be to use a [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), and to iterate numbers (from lower up) until you find `n` such that `n.multiply(n).toString()` matches the pattern.

Verifying if the pattern matches can be done easily with a regex, after doing `toString()` on the resulting squared number.

Regex:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(
      "1[0-9]2[0-9]3[0-9]4[0-9]5[0-9]6[0-9]7[0-9]8[0-9]9[0-9]0").matcher("");
```

And invoke with:

```
m.reset(myString);
m.matches()
```

the `matches()` will return true if and only if `myString` matches the pattern

---

**EDIT:**

Use optimizations suggested by @The111 to improve performance, the idea still remains - iterate and check if the result matches the pattern.

Comment: how could I verify that the pattern has matched?

Comment: Is there an advantage to using `BigInteger` over `long`?

Comment: @The111: Not really, tried to be more generic for large numbers (and not the specific numbers at hand), if it fits then a `long` will be faster and probably better.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal: Not rally, `" " + n*n` for long will have the same affect, if they are enough of course.

Comment: @amit: why you have empty string ("") in `.matcher("")`?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal: You need to feed it with something when you creating the matcher.. However, it is better to use a single matcher and not to recreate it every iteration. So, we simply feed a dummy empty string, and `reset()` the matcher with the real string before every time we check for match

Comment: and I think `myString` is `String myString=n.multiply(n).toString()`. Am I right?